# Alternative to Trigger Action method

Tags: node.js, botframework

In bot framework v3, LUIS interruptions were handled using trigger action method. What's the alternative to be used in bot framework v4 node.js?

Comment: In my bot, user can go with a selected flow. If the user ask questions that are related to another flow, the bot should cancel the current dialog stack and begin the new dialog set. The problem is though the new dialog begins, when selecting a choice from the new dialog's prompt it goes back to the old,cancelled dialog

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at sample [13.core-bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.core-bot) from the Botbuilder-Samples GitHub [repo](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples).

Essentially, you have a 'cancel' dialog that listens for interruptions. You then extend other dialogs off of the 'cancel' dialog. This allows user statements flagged as an interruption (`help`, for example) to be picked up and any associated logic to occur. In this case, `await innerDc.context.sendActivity('[ This is where to send sample help to the user... ]');` is sent as the `help` response.

CancelAndHelpDialog:

```js
class CancelAndHelpDialog extends ComponentDialog {
    async onBeginDialog(innerDc, options) {
        const result = await this.interrupt(innerDc);
        if(result) {
            return result;
        }
        return await super.onBeginDialog(innerDc, options);
    }
    async onContinueDialog(innerDc) {
        const result = await this.interrupt(innerDc);
        if(result) {
            return result;
        }
        return await super.onContinueDialog(innerDc);
    }
    async interrupt(innerDc) {
        const text = innerDc.context.activity.text.toLowerCase();
        switch(text) {
            case 'help':
            case '?':
                await innerDc.context.sendActivity('[ This is where to send sample help to the user... ]');
                return {
                    status: DialogTurnStatus.waiting
                };
            case 'cancel':
            case 'quit':
                await innerDc.context.sendActivity('Cancelling');
                return await innerDc.cancelAllDialogs();
        }
    }
}
```

BookingDialog extending CancelAndHelpDialog:

```js
const { CancelAndHelpDialog } = require('./cancelAndHelpDialog');

class BookingDialog extends CancelAndHelpDialog {
  constructor(id) {
    super(id || 'bookingDialog');

    [...]
  }

  [...]
}
```

Hope of help!